# Create Authentication Login page with Firebase in SwiftUI, not UIKit

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, swiftui, xcode11

So I've started a brand new project (no code other than "Hello World"), and have installed and implemented Firebase into my AppDelegate successfully, but there are no videos/ tutorials anywhere that can help with actually creating a login page in SwiftUI - Everything is in UIKit, which I have no idea how to use. I know its a very broad question, but I really don't know what to do as I don't want to learn UIKit right as I was getting the hang of SwiftUI. I also don't like the look of storyboards, but unrelated.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. It sounds like you're asking how to work with views in SwiftUI?

Comment: No I understand Views, just didn't understand how to use firebase with SwiftUI, I know how to do navigation, environment/observableObject and all that stuff though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The link](https://benmcmahen.com/authentication-with-swiftui-and-firebase/) worked, I just had to change the session to have an email property as well, and some little things